# Is there any way to return a View and ResponseBody at the same time using only one method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need some help from you all. Basically it has a base path at the class level (/grade), So the first method will return the jsp page to the user and second method will actually handle the request send from the client using xhr with GET method. So when it send the response I am able to handle it, but when i try to reload with the url http://localhost:8080/grade/12323 it returns me object not the page.

```
    @GetMapping
    public String getGradePage(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("1010000001");
        user.setPassword("b");
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        
        List<Course> courseList = gradeService.getAllClassById(user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("courseList",courseList);
        return "lecturer/submit-grade";
    }
    @GetMapping("/{courseCode}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Enrollment> submitGrade(@PathVariable String courseCode) {
        
        List <Enrollment> enrollmentList = gradeService.getAllStudentEnrollmentById(courseCode);
        
        return enrollmentList;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just solved it by changing the endpoint in my javascript xhr, what a silly mistake ..